# MySQL Installation MySQL Server Failed 5.7.19

Tags: mysql, server

Fail Image

[image]

During installation of MySQL msi installer this status of MySQL Server showed up, no idea how to fix.

My Operation System: Windows 7

Comment: _First Thought_ Do you already have a MySQL Server running on your system?

Comment: The error message/log is not shown, where MySQL server is mentioned. Please check, if there is MySQL already installed, maybe you have to stop the MySQL service before installing.

Comment: Check the following: `MySQL Community 5.7 Server requires the Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package to run on Windows platforms.`, see [2.3 Installing MySQL on Microsoft Windows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-installation.html).

Answer (score 6):

i have solved the same problem...it arises because we have installed 64 bit Visual Studio 2013 Redistributable but the installer is 32 bit . installer desn't recognise Visual Studio 2013 Redistributable .install 32 bit version and problem got solved,download link
https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/6/2E61CFA4-993B-4DD4-91DA-3737CD5CD6E3/vcredist_x86.exe

Comment: try to use custom installation to install mysql server and then post the report

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem and can't be fix.

Eventually, I use the installer of 5.7.16 to skip this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have `Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x86)` installed if you want to install the server in a `32bit` system.

However, to install the server in `64bit` system, you will need `Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x86)` and `x64` installed. As **@mukesh yadav** said, this is because the *MySQL Installer* is *32bit* therefore requires Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x86) while the *64bit* server requires Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x64)

Comment: your point *need Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x86) and x64 installed* actually saved my day. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when trying to help out a colleague.

The fix that ended up working was to use the "offline" installer instead.

The ~400 MB one here:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.7.html

[image: mysql]

Answer (score -1):

solved the problem.

i have continued the installation normally, eventhough there wasnt a finish button at the end, quitted from that.

Opened MySQL Workbench, Connect Database , still doesnt work.

then i started **wampserver**, and again Connect Database

**this time it worked!**

(wampserver - a program i used it previously so the database is the same from there.)

[Choose in the "Stored Connection" : Local instance wampmysqlid64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqp6L.png)